# Windows.winmd in azure worker role

Tags: c#, azure, windows-runtime, azure-worker-roles

I need process video (trim, encoding and other) in azure worker role. I found nothing .net library. But i found windows.media in windows kit (winrt - Winows.winmd file). I referenced this metadata to azure worker, but it does not work (Error: Requested Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaEncodingProfile' is not registered.) I expect that this is due to azure worker role have not COM object's. But worker role based on Windows Server 2012, who have it. Someone has an idea? Or how can i process video in azure worker role.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with the Media Foundation and some others desktop experience components not being installed by default on a server.
You might need to write a [startup task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh180155.aspx) to install/enable features and maybe codecs you need.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed to make similar case working. After installing Media Foundation feature mentioned, WinRT API magically appeared.